# Создание Bitmap внутри статического класса вызывает RuntimeException `Stub!`

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Цель: создать класс, который будет возвращать `Bitmap`, на котором будет что-то рисовать.

Для этого провожу разработку с тестированием.

В `main()` внутри статического класса, который запускается в Android Studio на ПК, возникает ошибка при попытке создать `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:60)
    at ru.randgor.mygia.v4.Test.testGraph(Test.java:51)
    at ru.randgor.mygia.v4.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Предполагаю, что помимо `Bitmap` придётся создавать ещё и `Canvas`, создание которого:

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
```

Выдаёт:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:23)
    at ru.randgor.mygia.v4.Test.testGraph(Test.java:50)
    at ru.randgor.mygia.v4.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Какие есть варианты для решения данной задачи? Подобных вопросов нигде не нашёл.

Comment: метка `android-studio` не предназначена для вопросов не связанных с работой IDE!!!

Comment: @Andrew я не уверен что дело тут не в IDE, сложно сказать однозначно. Решение должно иметь возможность быть протестированным именно в этом IDE, ибо иначе оно не будет объективным

Comment: я думаю большинство отвечающих по метке `android` работают в Android Studio. Можете откатить мою правку, если все-таки вы считаете что данная метка необходима, но тогда не забудьте добавить и `android` тоже :)

Comment: Статический класс, который запускает Android Studio на ПК, это вообще зачем? Не надо тестировать AS, она не имеет среды исполнения, только компиляции.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja окей, тогда как мне разрабатывать компилятор JSON объектов в картинки? Мне каждое изменение компилить и проверять на телефоне? Это бред

Comment: На телефоне совсем не обязательно, для этого есть эмуляторы. Теория по теме тестирования: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals